# What is the Maximum Size in MB which can be load per SQL request in to a Webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ram, filesize

What is the Maximum Size in MB which can be load per SQL request in to a Webpage?
(PHP is the only way I've known)

I think the data which is come back from the Server will be saved in the RAM. Maybe it is the RAM-MB of the Hardware.

Is it better to save the data in a file if I have a lot of stuff?

Comment: how long is a piece of string

Comment: It depends how much memory you have allocated to your php process. Assuming this is a web process, run `phpinfo()` in a web page to find out. You can increase this if necessary, but if you find you need more than, say, 100M, you are probably trying to do too much in a single page.

Comment: It depends on the settings in the setup, you might want to post some code so we can help you.

Comment: a 100M web page is not friendly to the user, you would encounter issues from the browser\user before you have issues related to the  server\php\mysql. If you have a specific issues, its better to post details of that rather than this vague broad question.

Comment: @Dagon, agreed - was referring to process size, not delivered page size. That would be more like 0.5M `:)`.

Comment: @halfer i understand, we can all only answer in generalities the question is to broad and vague to be answerable.

Comment: @BDP86: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @BDP86: please edit your question with more specifics if you can. Or were you asking just out of interest?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, the maximum size of a SQL statement is limited by the `max_allowed_packet` variable.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

The default setting (I believe) is 1MB, but it's possible to increase that significantly.

That's the limit on the size **" per SQL call "** set by MySQL.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question that was asked, and answered a fundamentally different question: "What's the maximum size of a SQL statement I can send to the database from PHP".

Comment: i recommend - vote to close and flee :-)

Comment: @Dagon: I voted. BTW. I measured a piece of string, it's exactly "1 string" long.

Comment: NO! I asked for the maximum size of a SQL return from a request :-)